# Add text information from Chrome HTML Document (.htm) to image in popup with freemarker?

Tags: geoserver, kml

I have created a popup that opens up the attribute table and a jpg-image. I want to add a descriptive text that I have placed in Geoservers http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/.

The text is in form of "Chrome HTML Document (.html)" in the same www directory. I have been able to print the ID to the picture, but not the text. For example, one photo can have the attribute PHOTO = 65 and ID = A205.

I have only been able to print the ID next to the image with this code in content.ftl:

```
<ul>
<li>
#list features as feature
<img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/inf/${feature.PHOTO.value}.jpg" ${feature.ID.value}/>
<li/>
#list
</ul>
```

The popup shows the image and the ID, but not the information contained within the html document.

I have tried creating a description.ftl and linking the www ID value to that file, but the content.ftl but it does nothing.

I am unsure what kind of src to use for the document since it is not an img.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but should be able to use the [`include`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html) directive to import a text document to include in your output. In your case I would do something like (assuming your html documents are called `A205_mydoc.html`):

```
<#include ${feature.ID.value}+"_mydoc.html" parse=false>
```

The parse option being false saves freemarker from having to check if there are any template variables in the document.

Comment: I get a "Template not found for A301_mydock.html" error. I put the include after the list in my ul, tried several options with only _mydock.html aswell.

Comment: what is your HTML document called? and where is it stored?

Comment: It is several documents that are tied to the photo by the ID number. So photo 1322 = ID 32, 1345 = ID 45 etc. That ID contains a html document which in turn contains information. They are in my \webapps\geoserver\data\workspaces\www\

Comment: please give me an example of a single file name!

Comment: One file name can be 301.html

Comment: so you should include `${feature.ID.value}+".html"` (if 301 is an ID)

Comment: I tried with <img src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/inf/${feature.PHOTO.value}.jpg"/> ${feature.ID.value}+".html"  and <#include> but it only says 301+".html".  Must have placed it wrong.

Comment: Look at the answer I have written - then read the page I linked to and then adapt my solution to your situation. You need to write `<#include ${feature.ID.value}+".html">` in your template so free marker can *include* it in your output